# Shortcut for changing constraint angle of the Knife tool?

Tags: knife-tool

In Blender 2.93 I could enable the Knife tool's angle constraint by pressing <kbd>C</kbd> shortcut. By default, it was snapping to 45°. In Blender 3.0 default angle constraint changed to 30°. I know that I can choose the Knife tool in the toolbar, then change the angle constraint amount in the tool settings. But I prefer to use the Knife tool by pressing <kbd>K</kbd> shortcut, in that case Knife tool settings are available only through shortcuts, not through UI. So my question is how to make a 45° (or another angle) cut when I called Knife tool through <kbd>K</kbd> shortcut?

Comment: The constraint shortcut has changed from 'C' to 'A' in Blender 3.0 as shown on the bottom status bar.

Comment: @JohnEason Since he complained about the angle and not the use of the constraint per se, I guess he had already figured that out ;)

Comment: True and the defaults have indeed changed to 30 degree steps from 45 degree, but I'm a bit confused by your "you can set a custom angle for the Knife Tool on the toolbar as well" statement below? I assume you mean the tool options on the 'N' panel? The problem is that you have to have the N panel open and set to 'Tool' before you actually initiate the knife tool! :^(

Comment: @JohnEason but it can be also changed from **"A"** back to **"C"** in **Knife Tool Modal Map**

Comment: @Crantisz Which would also mean that you'd have to change the 3.0 'Cut through' shortcut which was originally 'Z' in previous versions! :^)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be defined in keymap in user preferences:

[image]

(3D View → Mesh → Mesh (Global))

BTW shortcut can be changed from <kbd>A</kbd> back to <kbd>C</kbd> in **Knife Tool Modal Map**

Comment: You were quicker than me ;)  @Cake_Seller: By the way, there you can set the snapping for _K_ and right below for _Shift+K_, so if you want you can have two different default angles. Or actually three different angles, you can set a custom angle for the Knife Tool on the toolbar as well.