# How can I model these quickly?

Tags: modeling

I have three question about modeling,they are all simple,but I can't find a quick way to do that.

- How can I cut a line in vertical?
  It's easy to make a cut between two point,but if I don't have the second point and want to cut a vertical line,how can I do it quickly?In other software,Shift always works,but I don't know how to do in blender.More over,if I can cut them in some other direction will be better,i.e. 45°.
  [image]
- How can I join those lines?
  If I want to make such cross shape,I use bridge to make it.But the problem is,even those lines are on the same plane,they will not really cross,no vertice generated,two parts are just overlapped.How can I add vertices to the point where lines cross quickly?
  [image]
- How can I add an even loop edge?
  I have a shape shows below,I want to add a loop edge,the distance to the boundary should keep the same.I have tried Edge Slide and Inset Faces,but they are all depends on percentage.The only way works is solidify the 2D model,bevel the boundary and then delete the part which I added by solidify.Is there a quick way to do that?
  [image]
  [image]

Here's the simple demo.
https://pasteall.org/blend/c30ee33c4e0d49b2a8bcdbdb7ca024f5

Thanks a lot.

Update,the third answer should be:1.add a face; 2. bevel the line and unclick Loop Slide in bevel settings.
[image]

Comment: Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: Please don't ask more than one question per post. Use the [edit] below, to break this into multiple posts so that each focuses on a single issue. Make as many separate questions as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to ask one question per topic. But anyway.

1. Knife tool has an angle constraint. It enables on <kbd>A</kbd> (After pressing <kbd>K</kbd>)

[image]

Here how you can set different angle constraint (for example 45° or 15°): [Shortcut for changing constraint angle of the Knife tool?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254013/shortcut-for-changing-constraint-angle-of-the-knife-tool/254017#254017)

2. There is an option for automerge. Split edges and faces makes vertexes if edges intersects. Turn on these 2 checkboxes and press <kbd>G</kbd> Like you want to move the faces, but don't move.

[image]

[image]

If you don't have this popover, open it here:

[image]

3. You can make uniform offset using Inset <kbd>I</kbd> face should be created and then removed:

[image]

Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+B, scroll one time to 1 middle cut and try different offset type (<kbd>M</kbd>):

[image]

Central face will be removed after operation

Comment: 1 and 2 works well, but 3 has problem, maybe I don't illustrate it clearly.The loop edge is out of the inner boundary,it's a little bigger not smaller.The boundary should keep the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help, they really works.